# The onWillPop method of the WillPopScope Widget is not called when pressing the back arrow in the web browser

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-navigation

I am developing a `website` using `Flutter`. When I navigate in the order `DashboardLayout -> ListEventsViewTable -> EditEventView` [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRcNP.png), and press the back arrow in the browser [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6vwO.png), `EditEventView Widget` is removed from the `Widget Tree`, which is what I expect. But when I navigate in the same order, reload the page in the browser [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnCDl.png), and then press the back arrow [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQX6U.png), the `EditEventView Widget` is not removed as in the previous case. When I try to control when the back arrow is pressed in the browser, the `onWillPop` method of the `WillPopScope Widget` is not being called.

Structure of the `Widget Tree`, at different times.
[image: Widget Tree 1]

[image: Widget Tree 2]

[image: Widget Tree 3]

[image]

My main problem is how can I make the `EditEventView` page to be removed from the `Widget Tree` whenever the view is left, no matter if it was using the arrows or directly buttons on the page. In case the answer is using `WillPopScope`, why doesn't it work for me?

I am using the `auto_route` package:

```
AutoRoute(
      path: RouteGlobals.dashboard,
      name: "DashBoard",
      page: DashboardLayout,
      guards: [IsAuthenticated, RoleGuard],
      children: [
        //Events
        AutoRoute(
          path: RouteGlobals.listEventsRoute,
          page: ListEventsViewTable,
          guards: [IsAuthenticated, RoleGuard],
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: RouteGlobals.createEventRoute,
          page: CreateEventView,
          guards: [IsAuthenticated, RoleGuard],
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          path: '${RouteGlobals.eventOpenedRoute}/:id',
          page: EventOpenedView,
          guards: [IsAuthenticated, RoleGuard],
        ),
        AutoRoute(
            name: "EditEventView",
            path: '${RouteGlobals.editEventRoute}/:id',
            page: EditEventView,
            guards: [IsAuthenticated, RoleGuard],
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

`EditEventView`:

```
(...)
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _eventProvider = Provider.of<EventProvider>(context);
    final screenSize = Provider.of<ScreenSize>(context);

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        print("going back!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); // never printed when pressing on back arrow.
        context.router.navigate(CreateEventView());
        return Future(() => true);
      },
      child: (loadingEvent || savingEvent)
          ? SafeArea(
              child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                      width: 120.0,
                      height: 120.0,
                      child: const CircularProgressIndicator())))
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              child: (...)
(...)
```

I have searched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322093/how-to-configure-go-back-button-in-browser-for-flutter-web-app), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73903265/willpopscope-not-working-with-go-router-web-flutter), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60286839/flutter-android-back-button-does-not-call-onwillpop-of-willpopscope), but still no answer.

Comment: I have the same problem, any update?

Answer (score -2):

are you using routes?

tried this?

```
onWillPop:() async {
     print("returned")
     return await true;
}
```

Comment: In my problem description, I clearly stated that the `onWillPop` method doesn't work for me because it's never called.